How can I connect 2 OV2640 Cameras to esp32s3 and capture frames from both of them using esp_camera lib?
As we Esp32S3 has two cores and aslo has 2 i2c ports, I know this lib is written in C, so it is kind of difficult for me to use all the components of this lib as objects as we do in CPP.
I just want to initialize multiple cameras using this lib, now the init and deinit functions are there, but after initializing a camera once and again deinitializing it, doesnt make any sense, as it will stop the camera when the XCLK pin is stopped [clock for the camera basically].
Like wouldnt we be able to use both the I2C ports, and a pair of the data pins[d0-d7], sync pins[Horz and Vert] and clk pins[Pclk and Xclk]
And run both the cores to handle each camera separately, in low resolution [just to save space and to store both the frames of different cameras in DRAM]
You can find the esp_camera.h here
I know this might be not effecient, I am doing it for learning pupose, and please help me to understand , how can we just simply connect 2 cameras [OV2640] to an esp32S3 and capture frames using a single or separate core.
Can we do this by modifying the lib, or is there any way to use multiple instances of the methods in camera lib, without deinit the camera and re init it with a different config [cause thats really bad way].
I have been here and there asking this, didnt got much support, some guys just started to say this is stupid and not possible, I know this might be stupid, but I also dont understand why this is not possible[i think it is], and why not someone can just answer a question instead of critisizing it.
Also this cpp wrapper for esp_camera lib, will it work the way I am asking, the main lib is C though
Now this post is my last hope.

From a (very brief) look at the library, it does indeed not seem to be designed to support more than one camera at the same time. I'm sure it could be modified to do so, by someone with enough motivation. I wouldn't want to try it.

thanks for the reply @pmacfarlane, i have a little experience writting a custom cam lib for PicoRp2040 for the same Module I have, I know its painfull and Time taking.
Is there any way of using the existing lib by writting a cpp wrapper around it or modifying it a lilbit.
If you wwould how would you approach this problem.

From a high-level perspective, yes, you'd probably want to use C++, and make a class for a camera. Then move the global variables in esp_camera.c such as static camera_state_t *s_state into the class as member variables. But this is going to involve modifying the existing library, not magically wrapping it as-is.

modification like,[ one I saw that have to change the part were the lib initializes the I2C ports and Pins] can you point some just for refference.
Anyways, thanks a lot @pmacfarlane , guess I have to grind a little more

A possible hack: Change [conflicting] global variables into __thread (thread local storage) variables and use a different thread for each camera instance. For example, in driver/esp_camera.c, you could try static __thread camera_state_t *state; Otherwise, from a cursory look, most functions don't use global variables and take pointers to structs that have been malloc'ed. I could be wrong about this, but there appears to be just a small handful of globals you'd need to change.

also @CraigEstey can you suggest me some guide/doc/refference/book/video which can help learn more about the properties of C , like you said about the __thread, I am still learning, but didnt knew the langauge can be used like this

Try: The Definitive C Book Guide and List
